# I hear a loud grinding noise on front right tire of 2001 mazda tribute and brake pads and rotors are not bad

Tags: noise, mazda, tribute

It's only when I'm in gear not when braking

Comment: Welcome to the site! There's not much information in your question, more details would be useful. Does the noise change with speed, as in get louder the faster you go, or higher pitched? Did anything happen before this noise started? You also say it's only when you are in gear, if you coast in neutral does the noise persist?

Comment: Also does it get louder going around curves?